# Function to copy files

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create several buttons to copy files from a source to a destination.

My code is as follows:

```
Public Sub CopyInvoice001()
    Dim SourcePath As String
    Dim DestPath As String
    Dim FSO As Object
    SourcePath = Range("S2")
    DestPath = "C:\Test\"
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FSO.CopyFile source:=SourcePath, destination:=DestPath
End Sub
```

My question is whether it's possibe to create a function for this purpose or not. I am not very familiar with VBA, but I also wouldn't want to copy this extract for each button, too.

Comment: Why do you need a `Function`? My guess is you need an argument.

Comment: What is it that each button does differently eg it might be that the source path comes from a different cell (ie not always "S2") or that the destination path is different (ie not always "C:\Test\")? Then, how does the button control the value that varies for example you might say that "Button1" uses cell S2, "Button2" uses cell S3 etc ... suggest you provide more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Files Using Buttons

[image]

- It is assumed that each button's (Form Control) top left cell is in the same row as the row of each source file path in column `SRC_PATH_COLUMN`.
- Copy the code into a standard module e.g. `Module1`.
- To start from scratch, create a button and assign the main procedure to it. Place it accurately into a row (the width is not important). Copy it to all the rows with the source file paths. Optionally, you could search the internet to find out how to do it using a macro.

**Main**

```vb
Sub CopyFileUsingButton()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Copy File Using Button"
    Const SRC_PATH_COLUMN As String = "S"
    Const DST_PATH As String = "C:\Test\Destination"
    Const OVERWRITE_NO_CONFIRMATION As Boolean = False
    Const SHOW_COPY_MESSAGES As Boolean = True
    Const SHOW_FINAL_MESSAGE As Boolean = True ' only if not SHOW_COPY_MESSAGES
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Get the destination folder path.
    Dim dPath As String: dPath = GetFolderPathFSO(DST_PATH, fso, True)
    If Len(dPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Reference the button.
    Dim PressedButton As Variant: PressedButton = Application.Caller
    Dim btn As Button: Set btn = RefPressedButton(PressedButton, True)
    If btn Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Get the source file path (located in the same row as the button).
    Dim siFilePath As String: siFilePath _
        = CStr(btn.TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_PATH_COLUMN).Value)
    Dim sFilePath As String:
    sFilePath = GetFilePathFSO(siFilePath, fso, True)
    If Len(sFilePath) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Copy the file.
    If SHOW_COPY_MESSAGES Then
        ' Use it as a sub since the message in it will show what's going on.
        CopyFileFSO _
            sFilePath, dPath, fso, OVERWRITE_NO_CONFIRMATION, SHOW_COPY_MESSAGES
    Else
        ' Use it as a function to be able to show the final message.
        Dim WasCopied As Boolean:
        WasCopied = CopyFileFSO(sFilePath, dPath, fso, _
            OVERWRITE_NO_CONFIRMATION, SHOW_COPY_MESSAGES)
        If SHOW_FINAL_MESSAGE Then
            If WasCopied Then
                MsgBox "The file" & vbLf & vbTab & sFilePath & vbLf _
                    & "copied to the folder" & vbLf & vbTab & dPath, _
                    vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
            Else
                MsgBox "The file" & vbLf & vbTab & sFilePath & vbLf _
                    & "already exists in the folder" & vbLf & vbTab & dPath _
                    & vbLf & vbLf & "No action taken.", _
                    vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            End If
        End If
    End If
            
End Sub
```

**Help**

```vb
Private Function GetFolderPathFSO( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    ByVal fso As Object, _
    Optional ByVal ShowMessages As Boolean = False) _
As String
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Get Folder Path (FSO)"
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then
        If ShowMessages Then
            MsgBox "Could not find the path """ & FolderPath _
                & """!", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If

    GetFolderPathFSO = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)

End Function


Private Function RefPressedButton( _
    ByVal ApplicationCaller As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal ShowMessages As Boolean = False) _
As Button
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Reference Pressed Button"

    If Not VarType(ApplicationCaller) = vbString Then
        If ShowMessages Then
            MsgBox "Use a button to run the calling procedure!", _
                vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim btn As Button
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons(ApplicationCaller)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If btn Is Nothing Then
        If ShowMessages Then
            MsgBox """" & ApplicationCaller _
                & """ is not the name of a button!", _
                vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set RefPressedButton = btn

End Function


Private Function GetFilePathFSO( _
    ByVal FilePath As String, _
    ByVal fso As Object, _
    Optional ByVal ShowMessages As Boolean = False) _
As String
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Get File Path (FSO)"
    
    If Not fso.FileExists(FilePath) Then
        If ShowMessages Then
            MsgBox "Could not find the file """ & FilePath & """!", _
                vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If

    GetFilePathFSO = fso.GetFile(FilePath)

End Function


Private Function CopyFileFSO( _
    ByVal SourceFilePath As String, _
    ByVal DestinationFolderPath As String, _
    ByVal fso As Object, _
    Optional ByVal Overwrite As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal ShowMessages As Boolean = False) _
As Boolean
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Copy File (FSO)"

    ' Get the destination file path.
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = fso.GetFile(SourceFilePath).Name
    Dim diFilePath As String:
    diFilePath = fso.BuildPath(DestinationFolderPath, sFileName)
    Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = GetFilePathFSO(diFilePath, fso, False)
    
    Dim WasCopied As Boolean
    
    If Len(dFilePath) = 0 Then ' the destination file doesn't exist
        dFilePath = diFilePath
        fso.CopyFile SourceFilePath, dFilePath
        WasCopied = True
        If ShowMessages Then
            MsgBox "Copied" & vbLf & vbTab & SourceFilePath & vbLf & "to" _
                & vbLf & vbTab & dFilePath, _
                vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
    Else ' the destination file exists
        If Overwrite Then
            fso.CopyFile SourceFilePath, dFilePath, True
            WasCopied = True
        Else
            If ShowMessages Then
                Dim Msg As Long
                Msg = MsgBox("The file """ & dFilePath & """ already exists. " _
                    & vbLf & vbLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", _
                   vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, PROC_TITLE)
                If Msg = vbYes Then WasCopied = True
            End If
        End If
        If WasCopied Then
            fso.CopyFile SourceFilePath, dFilePath, True
            If ShowMessages Then
                MsgBox "Copied (overwrote)" & vbLf & vbTab & SourceFilePath _
                    & vbLf & "to" & vbLf & vbTab & dFilePath, _
                    vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            End If
        End If
    End If

    CopyFileFSO = WasCopied

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the last two comments. They are very helpful and resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

BigBen suggests you just need to change the sub-procedure to accept source and destination as arguments then create other sub-procedures that you actually attach to the buttons to call the general sub-proceudre.  Here's what that looks like:

```
Public Sub CopyInvoice001()
    ' reads the path from S2
    CopyFile Range("S2").Value, "C:\Test\"
End Sub


Public Sub CopyInvoice002()
    ' reads the path from S3
    CopyFile Range("S3").Value, "C:\Test\"
End Sub


Public Sub CopyInvoice003()
    ' reads the path from whichever cell is active
    CopyFile ActiveCell.Value, "C:\Test\"
End Sub


Public Sub CopyFile(SourcePath As String, DestPath As String)
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FSO.CopyFile source:=SourcePath, Destination:=DestPath
End Sub
```